# How do I make a link unclickable?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there some CSS property or something that I can use with my anchor tag so as to make it unclickable or I HAVE to do stuff in code behind to get what I want?

**[edit]**
`onclick=return false;` is refreshing the page.. I dont want that.. want this anchor tag to appear as a plain text.. actually I have css applied on anchor tag.. so cant change it to simple lable or whatever

Comment: Do you want its presentation as non clickable text or its behavior?

Comment: If you don't want text to be clickable, don't make it a link.

Comment: You can't trust what's going on client side. So you have to deny access to the link on the server either way.

Comment: behavior..need it as an anchor tag only

Comment: I want it as a link only..just don't want it to clickable..I set its property "Disabled=true" in code behind..didnt work

Comment: Link doesn't has a property called : disabled ...

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you want the anchor tag to be a link destination, but not a link source then omit the href attribute and only have a name attribute. The HTML 4.01 spec allows this and suggests that browsers display the text within the href-less anchor tag as normal text.

Comment: Remember not to use just `a` but `a:link` and `a:visited` for your real links. The same applies to `:hover`: use `a:link:hover` and `a:visited:hover` instead of just `a:hover`.

Answer (score 57):

The `pointer-events` CSS property can be set in [modern browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events#Browser_compatibility) on a particular graphic element and tells under what circumstances the element can become the target of pointer events.

The `none` value makes sure that the element is never the target of pointer events and prevents all click, state and cursor options on the element.

```css
a {
  display: inline-block;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com" onclick="alert('clicked on link')">
  <svg width="140" height="140" onclick="alert('clicked on svg')">
    <rect x="10" y="10" width="120" height="120" stroke="#42858C" stroke-width="10" fill="#3E4E50" />
  </svg>
</a>
```

**However**, pointer events may target its descendant elements if those descendants have pointer-events set to some other value. In these circumstances, pointer events will trigger event listeners on this parent element as appropriate on their way to/from the descendant during the event capture/bubble phases. - [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events#Values)

```css
a {
  display: inline-block;
  pointer-events: none;
}
a svg {
    pointer-events: fill;
}
```

```html
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com" onclick="alert('clicked on link')">
  <svg width="140" height="140" onclick="alert('clicked on svg')">
    <rect x="10" y="10" width="120" height="120" stroke="#42858C" stroke-width="10" fill="#3E4E50" />
  </svg>
</a>
```

Comment: Even then you can click the link.

Comment: Cool learned something...pointer-events! It really can't click.

Comment: Caution: if you have an image inside your link tag, it won't be draggable or right-clickable

Comment: cursor property doesn't work for me, also in your example, any idea why it could be?

Comment: Cursor style may differ based on `pointer-events` value on parent or its descendant elements. Unless you set cursor explicitly.

Answer (score 17):

```
<a href="abcd.html" onclick="return false;">abcd</a>
```

Answer (score 7):

including an `onclick="return false"` attribute on the 
anchor element does the trick.  While this solution uses javascript and 
not css

Comment: Note that won't work if Javascript is disabled. Also "Open Link in New Tab" will still work and web crawlers will still follow this link. So I don't think it's an ideal solution.

Answer (score 5):

You can use

```
disabled="disabled"
```

in the anchor tag, I believe - that's what I do on csharpindepth.com, anyway. I wouldn't like to swear to how widely supported it is, admittedly - you probably want to check that. Seems okay on Chrome, IE and Firefox though. I don't know if there's an equivalent just in CSS.

Note that I believe this will make the link *visibly* unclickable (however the browser wants to do that) rather than just not do anything.

EDIT: I've just tried this on a local file, and it doesn't work... whereas it definitely works on csharpindepth.com. Worth trying then, but also probably worth looking at other approaches :)

EDIT: As BoltClock notes, this isn't strictly valid HTML - which may mean it will only work in quirks mode, for example. (That could explain my failure to produce it locally.)

You're probably better off with a JavaScript solution along with a CSS style to change the link appearance... but I'll leave this answer here just for the record.

Comment: Oh, Jon Skeet is answering also to html-related questions ;-)

Comment: It works, but `disabled` is not a valid attribute of `<a>`, if OP cares about HTML validity.

Comment: @BoltClock: Thanks, noted in the answer. It's a pretty dubious way of doing it, by the looks of things. Worth leaving up, I think, but I've noted that it's probably not the best approach.

Comment: validator.w3.org says it is incorrect way of doing it. `Attribute disabled not allowed on element a at this point`. I think pointer-events is the best way to disable it, however it will not allow to user `cursor: not-allowed` (which is a pity)

Answer (score 5):

Here is the pure HTML/CSS solution :

1. remove the "**href**" tag, and put your anchor in the "**name**" attr (you probably knew this already)
2. Add the following style to your link :

   ```
   a{ text-decoration: none; cursor: default; }
   ```

You should target the anchor styles using named attributes, so all your links dont become "unclickable", like so :

```
a[name=*]{ text-decoration: none; cursor: default; }
```

Named attrs wont work in IE 6 (probably not in 7 either). A completely cross browser solution is to add a class to the anchors, and target that. Ex :

```
a.anchor{ text-decoration: none; cursor: default; }
```

Note: The above styling makes the links "appear" unclickable. If one of the a tags had an href you could still click it and it would "go somewhere" or "do something".

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

This pretty works for me. Add a class of disable to your a tag. and this code snippet to your css

```
a.disable {
pointer-events: none;
cursor: default;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use CSS :

```css
.x{
  pointer-events: none;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="https://www.google.com" class="x" />Unclickable Google Link</a>
<br>
<a href="https://www.google.com" class="" />Clickable Google Link</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: how to make it clickable again ?

Answer (score 1):

Place a block style="position:absolute" right before the anchor tag and size it to overlay the content. Not sure why you want to make it unclickable most people are wondering how to make the links in a layered html clickable http://wsmithdesign.wordpress.com/2010/10/20/layering-html-with-absolute-positions-in-fluid-html/

Answer (score 1):

If the anchor element is a server side element, remove the href attribute.
anchor.attributes.remove("href");

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to add anchor then use this html code

Use this html code before where you want to put anchor

`<a id="Write Your Anchor Here" class="invisible"></a>`

i.e

`<a id="anchor" class="invisible"></a> How to Put Anchor`

or

```
<div id="youranchorname" class="anchor">
```

https://www.example.com/2016/11/how-to-add-html-code#anchor

by using this url the visitor will directly reached to the how to put anchor part in the post
Thanks

> **Note :** This url is just used for example purpose. It is not a working URL and your div tag must be closed with `</div>`

Comment: This code is also useful for blogspot users. I used this code on my blogger website

Comment: https://muhammadaqibhussain2016.blogspot.com/2016/10/muhammad-aqib-hussain-2016-android-app.html#direct

Comment: @coatless this answer was ok or not
please help me to improve my answers
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I ran into similar problem at react-router-dom {NavLink}. I had needed NavLink that represents Categories && triggers 'active' on child NavLinks && has defined 'href' attribute (or 'to' in my case) && be unclickable because I don't have pages there.
That is my solution in my case

```
<NavLink to='someCategoryPath' onClick={(e) => e.preventDefault()}>
   {title}
</NavLink>
```

..and maybe in your case:

```js
document.getElementById('x').addEventListener('click',(e) => e.preventDefault())
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="https://www.google.com" id='x' >Unclickable Google Link</a>
<br>
<a href="https://www.google.com"/>Clickable Google Link</a>
</body>
</html>
```

P.S. Cursor can be changed in CSS.

P.S.2. I know that this question was asked 12 years, 3 months ago