# Element click using javascript only

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say I have the following markup:

```
<a href="#ada">Test Link</a>
<a href="#" id="next">Next</a>
```

On `#next` I add listener to listen `onclick` event which then do trigger click to `a[href="#ada"]`. How to make the link `a[href="#ada"]` unclickable using mouse pointer? I know it can be done if I omit `href` attribute, but I can't do that.

Javascript stuff:

```
$('#next').on('click', function(e){
    // doing something
});
```

Comment: Please share javascript

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN: oh man it's just a simple `onclick` listener..anyway check updated question.

Comment: how u trggered a[href="#ada"]

Comment: On which element you move mouse?

Comment: `$('a[href="#ada"]').click()`

Comment: You can refer following link for you problem [http://stackoverflow.com/a/3984736/3732980](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3984736/3732980)

Comment: Any reason you’re not just setting the href of that second link to `#ada` as well in the first place? (Or by script, if you can not modify the HTML code.)

Comment: And `pointer-events: none` has fairly decent browser support.

Answer (score 2):

You can disable submit with this

```
$("#form_id").submit(function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

And to trigger submit you can use this

```
$("#trigger_id").click(function() {
    $( "#form_id" ).submit();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add a onclick="return false" attribute to anchor tag.

```
<a href="#ada" onclick="return false">Test Link</a>
<a href="#" id="next">Next</a>
```

Well i just checked and it works for me. Clicking anchor tag does nothing

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **[preventDefault()](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)** :

```
$('#next').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: sorry if my post isn't clear enough. from what i understand, your code prevent click event being fired on `#next` element. but what I want to do is to click `a[href="#ada"]` using javascript (`$('a[href="#ada"]').click()`) and prevent/disable click using mouse on `a[hef="#ada"]`

Answer (score 0):

One very easy and basic way is to cover that with an opacity 0 div :

```
<div style="opacity:0;position:absolute;margin-top:40px;width:200px;height:40px" ></div>
<a href="#" id="next">Next</a>
```

The above example just try to get the concept and may be varied.