# How can i make anchor unclickable after 10 seconds?

Tags: javascript, html, css, function

```html
<html>
    <head>
    <style>
    .inactiveLink {
        pointer-events: none;
        cursor: default;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <p> You have won a prize. Click <a href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank">here</a> within <div id='clock'></div> seconds ...</p>
    <script>

    var time = 10;
    var f = function counttime(){document.getElementById('clock').innerHTML--;}
    function stoptime(){cleatInterval(f);}

    if(time){
        document.getElementById('clock').innerHTML = time;
        var h = setInterval(f,1000);
        setTimeout(function(){clearInterval(h);
                    document.getElementById('clock').innetHTML = "Time's up!";
                    }, time*1000);
    }


    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to create a basic webpage, that says "You have won a prize. Click here within 10 seconds ..." when it opens. You have 10 seconds to click "here" to get your prize. After 10 seconds, "here" should be unclickable. I added a CSS part about being unclickable, which is called "inactiveLink". I don't know how i should implement the change of anchor tag after 10 seconds, to JS. (I'm thinking about after 10 sec, a in HTML should be changed to a with id inactiveLink)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make a link unclickable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3984726/how-do-i-make-a-link-unclickable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there :)

I would use a class that uses the CSS-rule `pointer-events: none` and then use JS to add that class to the link after 10 seconds:

```js
const a = document.getElementById('a');

setTimeout(() => a.className = 'unclickable', 10000);
```

```css
.unclickable { pointer-events: none; }
```

```html
<a id="a" href="">Hurry up</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [setAttribute](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_setattribute.asp) to make it unclickable. Maybe make a class called "unclickable" with all of the CSS you want.

You can see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3984726/how-do-i-make-a-link-unclickable) for more information on how to set your link so that it won't fire an event upon click. Check the second answer (not the one that the user marked as correct).

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it is by removing the attribute href **`removeAttribute("href");`.**

**Note**: that `pointer-events:none` only prevents mouse clicks but if you used the tab key and pressed ENTER over the link it will still be followed.

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("anc").removeAttribute("href");
}
```

```html
<a id="anc" href="google.com">Click Me.</a>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Disabler</button>
```

Comment: I will definitely take your idea as a good point. But im trying to improve myself so, i can stick with simpler ones for now. Again, appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

anchor tags dont have a `disabled` attribute, but one approach you can take is to style a button like a link. Something link this for example:

```js
const buttonEl = document.querySelector('#target');
const handler = e => {
  console.log('Button is still active!');
};

buttonEl.addEventListener('click', handler);

setTimeout(() => {
  buttonEl.disabled = true;
}, 2000);
```

```css
button {
  all: unset;
  color: blue;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

button:disabled {
  color: gray;
  cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

```html
<button id="target" type="button">Click the button</button>
```